# Litecoin core account info result

Tags: wallet, litecoin

I'm using Litecoin RPC in my app. I created two wallets on my server. Make some send-receive operations and last result is like that:

```
{
    "result": {
        "": -0.381788,
        "wallet1": 0.11,
        "wallet2": 0.271788
    },
    "error": null,
    "id": 12729
}
```

What it means? When I send some coins from wallet2 then ("") this wallet is decreasing but wallet2 staying same value. I think wallet2 must decrease. What is the issue on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The current multi-account system is deprecated in Bitcoind (AFAIK Litecoind uses the same one) and has a bug that makes negative balances appear in accounts:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/9887